# Prove that if $X,Y$ are independent random variables with densities $f_X, f_Y$ then,

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables with densities $f_X, f_Y$ and cumulative distribution functions $F_X, F_Y$ respectively. Then:

$A)$ if $Z=max\{X,Y\}$, then $F_Z(z)=F_X(z)*F_Y(z)$ ;

$B)$ if $Z=X+Y$, then $F_Z(z)=F_X(z)+F_Y(z)$ ;

$C)$ if $Z=e^X$, then $F_Z(z)=F_X(e^z)$ for $z>0$ ;

I have to prove or disprove these subpoints. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is very straightforward to actually derive $F_Z$ in all cases and compare the expression you got with the expression that is given. For B you can easily see something is wrong, check the limit when $z\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(A)$, let's determine exactly what $F_Z$ is:
$$
F_Z(z) = P(Z \le z) = P( \max\{X,Y\} \le z )
= P(X \le z, Y \le z),
$$
since $\max\{X,Y\} \le z$ if and only if both $X \le z$ and $Y \le z$; hence, by independence,
$$
F_Z(z) = P(X \le z) P(Y \le z) = F_X(z) \cdot F_Y(z).
$$

For $(B)$, as Shashi says in the comment, take $z \to \infty$ and see what goes wrong.

For $(C)$, try to do the same *idea* as $(A)$: consider how to write $Z \le z$ in terms of $X$ when $Z = e^X$; this way you will derive an explicit expression for $F_Z$, and you can then determine if the claim $(C)$ is true or not!

---

To answer your comment, we can immediately say
$$
F_Z(z) = P(Z \le z) = P(e^X \le z) = P(X \le \ln z) = F_X(\ln z).
$$
Hence, as you correctly said, $(C)$ is not correct.

Note that if we define $Z'$ by $Z' = \ln Y$, then
$$
F_{Z'}(z) = P(Z' \le z) = P(\ln Y \le z) = P(Y \le e^z) = F_Y(e^z).
$$

Comment: $ (C) F_Z(z)=P(Z \leq z)=P(e^X \leq z)=P(ln e^X \leq ln z)=P(X \leq ln(z))$, so $ e^X \leq z \iff X \leq ln(z)$. But $F_X(e^Z)=P(X \leq e^z)=P(ln X \leq ln e^z)=P(z \geq ln X)$. So there's no equality?

Comment: Indeed you are correct :) -- I've just added some more details: hopefully these make it completely clear for you? :)